# gps tracking perfomance issue on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, gps, location, windows-phone

Made a quick app for a friend who walks his dog and he wants to know how far he walks and speed and stuff with high accuracy. Anyway I made the app track just the distance and location with a timer. Everything works ok but when it comes to updating the stats on the screen (performed every 8 seconds) there seems to be a performance problem as the time will pause and then jump 2 seconds as if to say that the update part is taking a second or 2.

Here is the code

```
List<GeoCoordinate> Locations;
Geolocator Locator = new Geolocator();
Locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
Locator.MovementThreshold = 1;
Locator.PositionChanged += Locator_PositionChanged;

DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
_timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
_timer.Start();
long _startTime = System.Enviroment.TickCount;

private void Locator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PostionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    CurrentLocation = args.Position;

    if(GetPositionTime >= 8) // Checks to see if 8 seconds has passed
    {           
       Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
       {
            GeoCoordinate cord = new GeoCoordinate(CurrentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude,
                                    CurrentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude);
         if(Locations.Count > 0)
         {
            GeoCoordinate PreviousLocation = Locations.Last();

            // This part will update the stats on the screen as a textbox is bound to
            // DistanceMoved
            DistanceMoved = cord.GetDistanceTo(PreviousLocation);             
         }

         Locations.Add(cord);
       }));
    }
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetPositionTime++;
    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Enviroment.TickCount - _startTime);

    // Update the timer on the screen
    Duration = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Comment: What is the Problem? That the timer does not work? Or that the GPS Signal was missing an update for one second, and upodated in the next?

Comment: No the problem is that when it updates the stats it takes 2 seconds to do it. so you get 00:08 then it stops and then it suddenly says 00:10. So the question is why is it slow at updating?

Answer (score 0):

UI controls need to be updated on the UI thread - wrap Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
around Duration and it should work.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
        Duration = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); 
}
```

Comment: If you read i am using a DispatcherTimer which executes on the UI thread. Plus that's not the problem.